# How to Convert Int to IntVar in Python Tkinter Module using SQLite/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, tkinter

So i'm building a project macro tracker using Python Gui Tkinter module.
I'm now trying to extra data from an SQLite database. The data extracted is type Int and I need to convert this to an IntVar so that I can use it as a textvariable in Tkinter's Label.
The Label(textvariable=) method required it be an IntVar in this case.

So just to summarize I need to convert an Int variable to an IntVar variable

Any help would be great,

```
def display_daily_macros():

    daily = sqlite3.connect('daily.db')
    data = pandas.read_sql_query("Select * from day", daily)
    data_time = data[data['sqltime'] == "2020-09-11"]
    all_info = data_time.sum()
    protein = all_info['Protein']
    print(type(protein))
```

Comment: i believe, you could do something like `IntVar().set(protien)`

Comment: Hi, would appreciate if you could mark an answer here

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this,

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

protien = '3' #this could be your value from the database
h = IntVar(value=protien) #declaring an IntVar and setting it to protien

e = Entry(root,textvariable=h) #assigning it to the entry widget
e.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Here your defining an `IntVar()` and then later using the `set()` method to make it `protien`.

Hope this is what your looking for.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried that earlier on and it comes back with "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'" any ideas?

Comment: @Thaskor could you show the code? Its hard to tell without the corresponding code

Comment: You can initialize an `IntVar` at the time of creation: `h = IntVar(value=protien)`